# CSS styling of HTML not getting rendered in SSRS

Tags: html, css, reporting-services

I have entered a text in SSRS as below.
`<strong><u><font size="3" style="background-color: rgb(153, 204, 255)">SPECIAL INSTRUCTION</font></u></strong> .`
In the text properties, I have checked the option 'HTML- Interpret HTML tags as styles'. But on running the report, the background color is not rendered.

Can anyone let me know the reason.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can check this code online it's working perfectly.

**SPECIAL INSTRUCTION**

**Your code is right**
Please make sure you are correctly defined.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>


<strong><u><font size="3" style="background-color: rgb(144, 04, 25)">SPECIAL 
INSTRUCTION</font></u></strong>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello Karthick,    Thanks for your response. The html was correctly defined and it was rendered successfully in SSRS report. Only issue here is the background color was missing. All others like font,u,strong were all displayed as expected.Is there any limitation in SSRS to interpret the css style given in the html?